# Using breakpoints with VS Code and a Quasar Vue App

Tags: debugging, vue.js, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, quasar-framework

I have a sample test project [here](https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/quasar_debug) which I am using to play with this.

What I would like to be able to do is set a breakpoint on the:

```
console.log('in returnArray')
```

line in the returnArray function in Index.vue, press play, and have VS Code stop so I can use the features of the debugger.

What I have been able to get to work is inserting the 'debugger' statement inside of the function to force a break into the debugger, which is still better then console.log(...) debugging, but not quite how I would like to work.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
            "breakOnLoad": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Running .scripts, I do see something odd, which seems wrong, but when I try to fix it, the 'debugger' statement does not cause VS Code to stop in the expected place.

```
› webpack-internal:///./src/pages/Index.vue (/Users/ericgorr/depot_quasar/quasar_debug/src/pages/Index.vue)
    - webpack:///./src/pages/Index.vue?2483 (/Users/ericgorr/depot_quasar/quasar_debug/src/src/pages/Index.vue)
```

You can see a double mention of the src folder. This is caused by

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
```

in the launch.json, but if I remove /src, the path in .scripts looks correct, but debugger stops working as expected.

Should I be able to set a breakpoint in VS Code and have it stop on that line? If so, what changes do I need to make to the project to get this to work?

Comment: Good Questions!!!

Comment: @WhitehorseJJ so, you have been able to replicate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Debugging icon in the Activity Bar to bring up the Debug view, then click on the gear icon to configure a launch.json file, selecting Chrome/Firefox: Launch as the environment. Replace content of the generated launch.json with the corresponding configuration:

[image]

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: firefox",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "pathMappings": [{ "url": "webpack:///src/", "path": "${webRoot}/" }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does not fix the problem. The breakpoint is not hit. Although, this does solve the path issue for Index.vue when using .scripts

Comment: Indeed, having the exaxt same issue and the breakpoint is simply ignored when lauching `Debug` with this config.